# Passing parameters to Prism modules

Tags: module, prism, mef

I am storing all my configurations in a module called Congigurations

Something like this:
**ConfigurationModule:**

```
[Export(typeof(ConfigurationModule))]
    public class ConfigurationModule : NotificationObject
    {
         public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I need to pass some value to **ConnectionString** from ConfigureAggregateCatalog after the module is beeing loaded.

What is the prism way of doing this, please provide some code.

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0):

I think Prism way is to fill `ConnectionString` from your `ConfigurationModule`, not from `ConfigureAggregateCatalog`. The idea is to separate responsibilities - your `ConfigurationModule` should load configurations, provide them to another modules and save them back to some repository if needed. Your `ConfigureAggregateCatalog` should do exactly as it's named - only configure IoC container, nothing more.

**UPDATE:**
In your scenario I suppose that you have something like `AuthenticationModule`. So, you can write something like:

```
[Export]
public class AuthenticationModule
{
  [Import]
  public ConfigurationModule { get; private set; }

  public void OnUserLoggedIn()
  {
    ConfigurationModule.ConnectionString = "your connection string";
  }
}

[Export]
public class AnotherModule
{
  [Import]
  public ConfigurationModule { get; private set; }

  public void DoStuff()
  {
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationModule.ConnectionString))
    {
      // user isn't logged in
    }
    var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationModule.ConnectionString);
  }
}
```

Comment: Suppose user logs in to the system and we want to fill his infomation in **ConfigurationModule** and reuse that information later on. Where one must do that, and how?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I really dont get what you are trying to achieve here. you have repeated ConfigurationModule in both classes, any explanation for that?

Comment: ConfigurationModule is marked as a dependency of AuthenticationModule and AnotherModule. Your IOC container (Unity or MEF) will see the [Import] directive and and inject an instance of you ConfigurationModule into the AnotherModule class. That way, AnotherModule can access the properties of ConfigurationModule (such as ConnectionString.)